# Add Icons On Android Application Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am building an android application and the activities has no icons of my application. How i can add icons on every activity of my android application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information is already widely available elsewhere (e.g. in the documentation).

Answer (score 3):

You can add icon in **manifest**:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/your_activity_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/your_icon">
```

Or in **onCreate** of activity:

```
 getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);          // for ActionBar
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);   //for Toolbar
```

Hope this helps.